# How to remove/volume down vocal from music using AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I am developing the app which required to Record audio when music is playing.
I can successfully record sound with music. But I can't remove vocal from music. It will also be great, if I can volume down of vocal when it rise.

I am using AVAudioSession, AVAudioPlayerNode for record while music playing.

Any help will be appriaciated.

Answer (score 0):

In WWDC14 session #502 "AVAudioEngine in Practice" you could find how to configure `AVAudioEngine` for Karaoke which is good for your task and also you could find information about node tap. Node tap can capture output from any `AVAudioNode`.

So you could add node tap for you `AVAudioInputNode` and record all you need:

```
AVAudioInputNode *node = [engine inputNode];    
// add tap
[node installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:4096 format[node outputFormatForBus:0] block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer, AVAudioTime *when) {
    // save audio buffer
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try to configure engine as suggested by you.